# Looking for a book with four-armed feline fighter-pilots looking for Earth

Tags: story-identification

About 20 years ago I remember reading a book about a race a feline people with four arms that were fighter pilots living on a carrier.  I believe they were created by humans.  They were trying to find Earth, which had become a myth.  The book kind of reminded me of Battlestar Galactica.  Anyone have an idea what book this was?  I believe it was part of a series.

Comment: I remember four arms, fighter pilots, wolf-like, not cat, metal instead of calcium in the bones.  The fighter craft had some sort of variable shaped "bubble" shielding that allowed them to fly through water as easily as air.  There was also a chess match, where the wolf man would quickly beat the best human player by taking unbelievable risks. Would have read it around '87-88. Same book?

Comment: The first thing that came to my mind was the kzin from Larry Niven's Ringworld books. I know there's a series about the man-kzin wars, but they don't have four arms and weren't created by humans.

Answer (score 8):

I think this could be [The Starwolves](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1683065.The_Starwolves) by [Thorarinn Gunnarsson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorarinn_Gunnarsson).

The timeframe is right (published in 1988) and the most of the details match

- Books are about a race of people called "Starwolves" or "Kelvessan"
- They have 4 arms, iron bones & electrical nervous system
- Live on large carrier ships & fly small fighters
- Created by an alien race for human Terran republic to defend against (human) Union
- Lost location of Earth/Terra thousands of years ago & are have been searching for it since

Only part that doesn't exactly match is that they are not explicitly described as feline .  However their appearance could be considered feline like - outsized eyes, large & pointed ears, small nose, slight stature, shaggy/soft hair.

There is a chess match where the protagonist starwolf, having never played the game before, defeats a human easily using unconventional moves.  There is also at least one scene where the starwolves fly their fighters under an ocean by reshaping their atmospheric shield into a needle shape.

Comment: That's the book *I'm* remembering.  Thanks Ben!