# Searching for novel involving space pilots with multiple arms

Tags: story-identification

I read a science fiction book in the early 90s, and I'd like some help finding it.

The only details I can remember are as follows:

- The characters lived on a large space ship together and had four or six arms
- they were renowned as excellent space fighter pilots
- there are humans as well
- the protagonist leads a group of ships into the city at the end of the book by using an underwater tunnel.

Comment: Did they have legs too, or [just arms](http://www.sfcovers.net/Magazines/ASF/ASF_0694.jpg)? Could you be thinking of the "quaddies" from [*Falling Free*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_Free) in the [*Vorkosi*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?241) series by [Lois McMaster Bujold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lois_McMaster_Bujold)?

Comment: I was just thinking that the only story like this that I'm familiar with is the Quaddies.

Comment: Falling Free was my first reaction as well, but the last point about the underwater tunnel does not fit, nor were they space fighter pilots.

Answer (score 4):

The book you are looking for is [The Starwolves](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1683065.The_Starwolves) by [Thorarinn Gunnarsson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorarinn_Gunnarsson).

- Book is about a race of people called "Starwolves" or "Kelvessan"
- They have 4 arms, iron bones & electrical nervous system
- Live on large carrier ships & fly small fighters
- Are far superior to normal human pilots due to their high G tolerance and reaction time
- At the end of the book a group of Starwolves fly their fighters into a human dome city via an underwater tunnel to rescue/retrieve the computer core of one their large carrier ships.

See my previous answer https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68418/33168 for more details